# Does Checkstyle 5.5 validates generics

Tags: java, coding-style, standards, checkstyle

I am using Checkstyle Eclipse plugin 5.5 to validate my Java project using standard coding style. I was wondering if Checkstyle generates any error/warning if I have not referenced generic types using parameters?

Now this warning is already shown as a type of Java problem. Just curious if Checkstyle also catches this (apart from manual configuration/tweak).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean, can Checkstyle detect something like `List list = new ArrayList();` as missing generic type arguments.

No, Checkstyle can't do that because it works only on the Java source files, so it would not know if the `List` you are referencing has type parameters or not. Checkstyle would have to determine the binary class name of `List`, and locate its source, which may not even be available in many cases.

[FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) may be able to do that, as it works on the compiled .class files. I don't know of a FindBugs rule which covers exactly your case, but there are other FindBugs rules related to generics.